# Global Module Installation for All Environments Python (Anaconda)

Tags: python, module, anaconda, environment

Recently I found myself lost in environments as I am learning deeply Computer Vision, and I am required to download a lot modules, libraries, and resources that are in common in all. I wonder if there is a way to download a module once, globally, and use it every time in all other environments by just importing/calling them?

Comment: This is a bad idea, how complicated can your environments be? Conda shouldn't download the same package twice anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pip freeze` or `pip3 freeze` to save list of all modules in your environment.

```
$ pip3 freeze > modules.txt
```

To install all modules saved in modules.txt on your new environment, use `pip install`.

```
$ pip3 install -r modules.txt
```

Comment: As I understood, I need to again download them in my environment still, right?

Comment: @WOOSAL Well it IS possible to install modules without downloading from internet. You could backup tar.gz files of each modules and then install manually in your new environment.

Comment: Oh, thanks in advance. Your answer will be ticked asap.

Comment: OP is using Conda, so will this do anything? Personally I don't even see how this answers the question.

Comment: @AMC the thing is I want to once downloading and installing the modules to use them by just calling them in my different environments, which looks kinda not possible I guess at the moment

Comment: @WOOSAL That's just repeating what you wrote in your post though, it still isn't clear why exactly you want to do this. It sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/628382) to me.

Comment: @AMC it is clear that if I had 10 envs, i had to install the same things for 10 times, which capture the space of my disks. And also sometimes confusing when you have not installed a module

Comment: _it is clear that if I had 10 envs, i had to install the same things for 10 times, which capture the space of my disks._ That shouldn't happen, Conda will not download the same thing over and over again. If that is happening to you, then it's probably a bug of some sorts.